# Add image button to the gridview row

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview, imagebutton

I  have added a row in gridview below the columns using datarow. I now wanted to add image button into that row that would support sorting of the columns.

My Question: How to add image buttons  into the first row of the gridview?

Below code shows how a new row is added.

```
DataRow drSampleRow= null; 

  drSampleRow= dtSampleDataTable.NewRow(); 
  drSampleRow["Col1"] = string.Empty; 
  drSampleRow["Col2"] = ResolveUrl("~/plus.gif"); //this doesn't works! 
  drSampleRow["Col3"] = string.Empty; 
  drSampleRow["Col4"] = string.Empty; 
  drSampleRow["Col5"] = string.Empty; 
  dtSampleDataTable.Rows.Add(drSampleRow);
```

Please guide me! Thanks!